# Does LoadDataSet implicitely close connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I am using microsoft.entrprise.libraries in an asp.net app.
I am calling LoadDataSet. The code below uses 'using' so this mean that
all resources will be cleaned up once that call has completed.

What happens when a call is made to the db and it times out and an error is thrown in the app, will the connection be closed?

Thanks,
Robert

```
public virtual void LoadDataSet(DbCommand command, DataSet dataSet, string[] tableNames)
{
    using (var wrapper = GetOpenConnection())
    {
        PrepareCommand(command, wrapper.Connection);
        DoLoadDataSet(command, dataSet, tableNames);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `using` statement actually expands to something like the following, so yes, if wrapper's `Dispose()` call releases all of the appropriate resources, then there is no leak (at least within the `wrapper` object):

```
var wrapper = GetOpenConnection()
try
{
    PrepareCommand(command, wrapper.Connection);
    DoLoadDataSet(command, dataSet, tableNames);
}
finally
{
    if (wrapper != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)wrapper ).Dispose();
    }
}
```